# How to set the widths of StatusStrip items?

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

I have the following:

```
StatusStrip
   ToolStripStatusLabel
   ToolStripStatusLabel
   ToolStripProgressBar
```

The `StatusStrip` is set to take the full width of the `WinForm`.

The first `ToolStripStatusLabel` is set to 200 pixels wide and the `ToolStripProgressBar` is set to 50 pixels wide.

How can I set the second `ToolStripStatusLabel` to expand to take up the rest of the `WinForm` width? I basically want the progress bar item to be always at the far right no matter the form width.

Comment: It is pretty rare that automatic layout pleases everybody.  The Spring property was designed to make an item stretch to fit the strip.  Works well on the *last* one.  Progress tends is more important than chatter so you'd rearrange the items to make the label last and gets its text truncated when it doesn't fit when the window is too small.  If you want to do it your way then you'll have to write the code to set the label's Width property.  Not hard to do either with the strip's ClientSizeChanged event.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for bring my attention to the **Spring** property. I have swapped my progressbar / statuslabel around and implemented it.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know if you want to provide some kind of answer as opposed to only a comment? That way I can accept it. Unless you want me to provide my own.

Comment: Just write it up yourself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was brought to my attention that I could use the [`Spring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.spring?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) property.

But this is designed to work on the **last** object on the status strip. So I adjusted the order of my objects accordingly.

Comment: Spring doesn't necessarily _have_ to be used on the last item. I like to have a label with spring, then a progress bar. This keeps the label to the left of the window, and shoves the progress bar to the far right of the window.